# Macro to copy and paste in next blank cell

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

```
Sub test1()
Dim LR As Long
LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(20, Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
Range("C3").Resize(, 3).Cut Destination:=Range("C" & LR)
End Sub
```

The above source code works to copy(cut) paste into same sheet.
Now i need cut and paste into another sheet 
ie: Sheet1(Cut) to sheet2(Past)

Thanks

Comment: `Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & LR)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will cut data from sheet1 to sheet2

```
Sub test1()
Dim LR As Long
LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(20, Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Resize(, 3).Cut 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks sathish sheets("sheet2") should add next to max(20, ......... Is there any possible to paste as spacial value. I'm using some formula in input area. Just i want to paste as value.