# Macro to Copy and Paste Sequentially

Tags: macros, copy, paste

I think this might help answer my question, I am just not savvy enough to understand it. - sorry if my question is redundant.
[Macro to copy and paste in next blank cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136372/macro-to-copy-and-paste-in-next-blank-cell)

I have a dynamic filter that allows me to find data within a data table and display the data in cells A1, B1 and C1
I then have a Macro that will copy data from cells A1, B1, and C1 and paste them to D1, E1, and F1 when I click a button assigned to the macro.

```
Range("A1:C1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

What I cannot find or figure out is how to modify the Macro to paste data to D2, E2 and F2 when I change my filter and run the macro/click the button for a second time.
Essentially, I am trying to create a list of data by clicking the button based on what my dynamic filter finds.

I hope this makes sense, and someone can help me.

Thank you!

---

Comment: It took some time, but I was able to identify a solution using ElseIf.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using ElseIf.  I am sure it can be done cleaner, but it does what I need it to do.  I can now assign the macro to a single button and click it multiple times to form my list.

```html
If Range("G23") = ("") Then
    Range("B23:D23").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G23").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
ElseIf Range("G24") = ("") Then
    Range("B23:D23").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G24").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```